# Import Error on Keras : 'can not import name 'abs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, keras, pip

I am trying to use keras for image classification. I want to load an already trained model (VGG16) for my project. but when I run

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
```

I get an error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'abs'
```

I reinstalled both tensorflow and keras using :

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

since I have found some suggestions that reinstalling could help on [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/46) though it was related tfp not VGG16.

Could someone help me, please? Why I am getting this error and how could I fix it?

OS:windows
Tensorflow and keras installed on CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after all trying to install tensorflow and keras in a virtual environment solved the problem. Still, don't know why this problem existed in the first place. steps are taken:

```
conda create --name vgg16project python # you can name it other than vgg16project
activate vgg16project
```

then install other packages you need such as pandas, seaborn etc. then installing tensorflow and keras with pip

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade keras
```

simply solved it. I guess there must be a reason why it is recommended to use tensorflow and keras in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue with keras cannot import abs.  Tried updating and found tensorflow file was still in use.

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32] The process
 cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\progra
m files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python36_64\Lib\site-packages\
\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

After uninstalling keras and tensorflow - I deleted the whole tensorflow folder and reinstalled both tensorflow 1.10 and keras.  This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just uninstalled (and deleted) tensorflow.

After that I installed it again with:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-rc1
```

I tried something like three different versions before getting it to work.